# Почему не отображается обьект заспавненный скриптом?

Tags: c#, unity3d

На самой сцене он есть, но его спрайта нет.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
{
    Instantiate(bullet, shotPoint.position, transform.rotation);
    timeBtwShots = startTimeBtwShots;
}
```

Выше код отвечающий за условие спавна

```
public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float lifetime;
    public float distance;
    public int damage;
    public LayerMask whatIsSolid;

    private void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit2D hitInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.up, distance, whatIsSolid);
        if (hitInfo.collider != null)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

выше кусок отвечающий за сам обьект [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

Как оказалось, это баг новой версии от 2020 года.
Я сломлен.
P.S. Выяснил, что баг этот не привязан к определенной версии и лечится путём создания другой, аналогичной точки спавна, на этом всё.

Comment: Сам ты баг, `Destroy(gameObject);` в `Update()` срабатывает.

Comment: Я в код никаких изменений не вносил, но стоило создать второй анологичный Shoot point и всё заработало, как это объяснить если не багом?